# Mathematical definition of a Wigner–Seitz cell

Tags: condensed-matter, definition, crystals

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a Bravais lattice generated by the primitive vectors $a_1,a_2,a_3$. We know that the [Wigner–Seitz cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Seitz_cell) of a lattice point is the region of space that is closer to that point than any other lattice point. Although this is easy to imagine, but not so easy to use formally, so is there a mathematical definition of the Wigner–Seitz cell? It should be independent of the primitive vector in the sense that the primitive vectors which generate the Bravais lattice are not unique.

Comment: But that is a mathematical definition. Perhaps not as easy to apply as you would like...

Comment: As Jon says, the definition is a mathematical one. Are you looking for a mathematical procedure for defining the geometry of the cell for any given set of basis vectors?